# How to truncate all tables of a given database in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, truncate

I have to execure in test environment the truncate of all tables of three different test databases. I need sql query that considers the table constraints because all the codes that I tested on AdventureWorks database are raising the following error:

Cannot TRUNCATE TABLE 'Person.CountryRegion' because it is being referenced by object 'vStateProvinceCountryRegion'

Comment: The error is telling you the problem. You can't `TRUNCATE` tables if they are being used by other objects; you'd have to `DROP` the blocking objects and then recreate them if you "must" `TRUNCATE` everything. Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) if I am honest.

Comment: I tried the following code https://gist.github.com/danguilherme/04fbe3906b46844f9351 that works but I cannot list manually the table names. Is there a code that truncate all the tables on a given database name? In my case the three test databses has hundreds of tables

Comment: As I mentioned, you can't just blindly `TRUNCATE` tables when constraints and schema bindings exist. You would have to `DROP` those first, and recreate afterwards. it's not a trivial task. I would, personally, suggest redeploying your database from your source control/database project as it'll contain no data in there (apart from any that might be mandatory for the application to work).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunatly I do not have the database project or creation scripts

Comment: Then you'll need to `DROP` the blocking objects, `TRUNCATE`, and then re`CREATE` the objects you `DROP`ed after the `TRUNCATE` completes. That will be a very manual task.

Comment: If you have problems with something on github, you should be raising an issue on the repository.

Comment: gist.github.com/danguilherme/04fbe3906b46844f9351 works, it's not required to add the list of tables, by default, I mean, if you don't uncomment any of the conditions, `@TablesToBeTruncated` is populated with the user tables in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
-- Disable all FK constraints...
EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL";
GO

-- TRUNCATE TABLES...

-- Enable all FK constraints...
EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL";
GO
```